# How convert a list to int[][]

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class piece where I define each piece shape.

```
myShape.Add(new piece
        {
            Height = 3,
            Width = 2,
            Name = "3x2 L TopRight",
            Size = 4,
            Shape = new int[][] {
                        new int[] { 1, 0 },
                        new int[] { 1, 0 },
                        new int[] { 1, 1 }
                    }
        });
```

But I create those shape by hand, now I reading the pieces in real time, so I create something like

```
List<int[]> virtualRow = new List<int[]>();
virtualRow.Add(new int[] { 1, 0 });
virtualRow.Add(new int[] { 1, 0 });
virtualRow.Add(new int[] { 1, 1 });
```

So how can I create Shape using virtualRow ?

I try something like

```
Shape = new int[][] { virtualRow.ToArray() }
```

But say

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[][]' to 'int[]'

Comment: Just curious, why are you fixating on using a 2D array in the first place.  Why can't `List< List<int>>` work for you?

Comment: @ryanyuyu This is only a mid step, final result will use a transformed 1D array with only offset to optimize speed. For example in a 3x3 grid that piece in TopLeft corner, become {0,3,6,7} but I will consider your suggestion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`virtualRow.ToArray()` is *already* an array of array of `int` values.  You don't need to create a new array of array of ints and add this to it.

All you need is:

```
Shape = virtualRow.ToArray(),
```

Answer (score 3):

virtualRow is a `List` of integer arrays, so to get an *array* of integer arrays you simply write:

```
Shape = virtualRow.ToArray();
```

...the return type of [List.ToArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx) being T[] as required.

Your code is in error because it attempts to *add* an `int[][]` to `Shape` instead of *creating* `Shape` as an `int[][]`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do the following:

```
Shape  = virtualRow.ToArray();
```

Since virtualRow is already a list of arrays. The `ToArray` function creates an `int[][]` object for your `virtualRow`, and all you need to do is store it to shape. What you were trying to do was create a matrix, within which was the result of the `ToArray` function. This way you are just storing the result of the function which gives you what you want.